# Electron 18.2 desktopCapturer not working in Ubuntu 22 LTS and Fedora 34

Tags: electron, ubuntu-22.04

```
desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'] }).then( sources => {
  fs.writeFile(`screenshot.jpg`, sources[0].thumbnail.toJPEG(25), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
      console.log('Image Saved')
  })
})
```

The above code was tested and working in ubuntu 18 and 20.
But its not working in Ubuntu 22 LTS and Fedora 34.
I have tested the app in electron 17. Screenshot image generated is empty and not working (size is 0 kb)

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'WebRTCPipeWireCapturer');
```

I have also enable WebRTCPipeWireCapturer at runtime in main.js

https://gitlab.com/seantaylor/electron-17-desktopcapturer-not-working

I have added entire code in above repository.
Please check the readme file for setup Instructions and running the application.

I have also raised a ticket in electron github, but got no solution.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/33961

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution.
Disabling wayland in ubuntu solves the issue.